# How to to retrieve the SQL type of the primary key of a related field mapped by Django's ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-1.8

I'm introspecting the types of some fields in a model, in particular I'm interested in retrieving the RDBMS-dependent type, i.e. `"VARCHAR(20)"`, and not the Django field class (`django.db.models.CharField` in this case).

I've problems with relationships, however, since the database mixes both tables with `varchar` primary keys and other with `integer` pks (so I can not make any assumption).

So far I've tried to retrieve the field type with the following code:

```
# model is a django.db.model class
for field in model._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False):
    try:
        # this code works for anything but relations
        ft = field.db_type(connection=connection)
    except:
        # I'm introspecting a relation -> I would like to retrieve the field type of the related object's pk
        ft = field.related_model.pk.db_type(connection=connection)
```

that, when dealing with a relationship, fails with the following error:

```
 'property' object has no attribute 'db_type'
```

when it fails, `field.__class__` appears to be a `ManyToOneRel` object, if this may be of any help. It's worth noting also that the code have to be compatible with new Django 1.8 `_meta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for related fields:

```
ft = field.related_model._meta.pk.db_type(connection=connection)
```

`model.pk` is indeed a property that gets you the value of the pk for a model instance. `model._meta.pk` is the actual `Field` instance that is the primary key for that model.

Comment: Thanks, @knbk, I really appreciated your help and the explanation you provided!